# grep in pipeline: why it does not work

Tags: grep, pipeline

I want to extract certain information from the output of a program. But my method does not work. I write a rather simple script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

print "first hello world."
print "second"
```

After making the script executable, I type `./test | grep "first|second"`. I expect it to show the two sentences. But it does not show anything. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape the expression.

```
$ ./test | grep "first\|second"
first hello world.
second
```

Also bear in mind that the shebang is `#!/usr/bin/env python`, not just `#/usr/bin/env python`.

Answer (score 2):

use  `\|` instead  of `|`

```
./test | grep "first\|second"
```